# Difference between prefetch (tf.data) and prefetch_to_device (tf.contrib)

Tags: tensorflow

The title itself is very complete but here is more clarification.

[prefetch_to_device()](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/data/prefetch_to_device?hl=ES) prefetches to a device.
How is it different from [prefetch](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset?hl=ES#prefetch) ? Does prefetch only fetches data to the memory ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understand `prefetch_to_device` allows you to prefetch data to GPU, which `prefetch` does not. Under the link below you may find @mrry comment made like 2 months ago.

> Both the (current version of the) tf.data API and the old queue-based
>   approach place the entire input pipeline on the CPU, and the GPUs are
>   exercised by parts of the graph that come after the input pipeline.

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/13610